# How to use Hook Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, hook, advanced-custom-fields

I am using One User Avatar to upload profile pictures from frontend. Link to plugin with documentation: https://github.com/onedesigns/one-user-avatar

In the documentation it says - If you're building your own profile edit page with other fields, One User Avatar is automatically added to the show_user_profile and edit_user_profile hooks. If you'd rather have One User Avatar in its own section, you could add another hook:

```
do_action( 'edit_user_avatar', $current_user );
```

Then, to add One User Avatar to that hook and remove it from the other hooks outside of the administration panel, you would add this code to the functions.php file of your theme:

```
function my_avatar_filter() {
    // Remove from show_user_profile hook
    remove_action( 'show_user_profile', array( 'wp_user_avatar', 'wpua_action_show_user_profile' ) );
    remove_action( 'show_user_profile', array( 'wp_user_avatar', 'wpua_media_upload_scripts' ) );

    // Remove from edit_user_profile hook
    remove_action( 'edit_user_profile', array( 'wp_user_avatar', 'wpua_action_show_user_profile' ) );
    remove_action( 'edit_user_profile', array( 'wp_user_avatar', 'wpua_media_upload_scripts' ) );

    // Add to edit_user_avatar hook
    add_action( 'edit_user_avatar', array( 'wp_user_avatar', 'wpua_action_show_user_profile' ) );
    add_action( 'edit_user_avatar', array( 'wp_user_avatar', 'wpua_media_upload_scripts' ) );
}

// Loads only outside of administration panel
if ( ! is_admin() ) {
    add_action( 'init','my_avatar_filter' );
}
```

What I'm trying to do is add One User Avatar to the user profile edit page but I don't have a clear idea of how to use the suggested hooks.

The idea would be to add One User Avatar to Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) fields: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/

or alternatively make it work with Profile Builder Pro: https://www.cozmoslabs.com/docs/profile-builder-2/

I have all the documentation, I have been looking for a solution for over 5 days and I have tried several times without success. As I'm relatively new to Wordpress and php, I don't have a clear idea of what steps to take.

Could someone give me a tip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, let me explain the concept of hooks in WordPress. Generally, hooks are execution points in WordPress, where on those specific execution points, data can be manipulated or content can be attached.
There are two types of hooks in WordPress
i)Action Hook
ii)Filter Hook

1. Action hooks are generally used to attach content or modify content without returning the content.
   E.g `do_action('hook_tag_name', $data)` -> This is how a hook is decalred in plugins for third party developers.
   Now if someone wants to modify the data on the 'hook_tag_name', then simply use this syntax here `add_action('hook_tag_name', 'callback_function', 10, 1)`. Inside this callback function 'callback_function', one can simply insert his/her own custom content like this e.g ->
   `function callback_function($data) {echo "Hello World!";}`
   Similar to the syntax above you can modify the content without returning it, in the case of filter hooks, you have to use the keyword 'return' inside the callback function attached to the hook. Also, the number '10' -> is the priority, 1 -> is the number of parameters passed within the hook. In this case '$data' is the parameter which is actually 1 parameter. You can pass multiple parameters like this -> `do_action('hook_tag_name', $data, $data2, ...)`
2. For filters, this is the syntax `apply_filters('hook_tag_name', $data)`. To modify the data inside the 'hook_tag_name', simply use this syntax here -> `add_filter('hook_tag_name', 'callback_function', 10, 1)`, where '10' is the priority of the filter hook for execution '1' is the number of data passed inside the filter hook. But please note that in terms of filter hook if a 'data' is passed on the filter hook, it needs to be returned, if it is not returned then it will throw an error. Here is how it would look like ->
   `function callback_function($data){ return $data; }`

Now back to your point, in your case `wpua_action_show_user_profile` is the callback function. define this function like this `function wpua_action_show_user_profile($current_user_object)`. You need to modify the `$current_user_object` profile image url. In order for the avatar to change, let me know if you need anything else. Or You can use this code to change the src of the avatar. This hook will help you ->
`add_filter('get_avatar_data', function($user, $data){var_dump($user);return $user;},10, 2);`. Make sure to var_dump the payload prior to applying any new-avatar link

Comment: Thank you for the exhaustive answer, you have been very kind. Unfortunately it is not within my competence, I give up. If there was a step by step guide I would be willing to follow it and learn, but this is too much for me.

I finally contacted plugin support and they just told me to put the One User Avatar shortcode in an ACF text field.

The solution almost worked, there is a problem with the profile update keys to solve.

Thanks again.

Comment: Dont just give up, shortcode is a different thing. But programmatically if you want to change the default wordpress user avatar then this is the correct solution. Also would you be kind enough to tell me where exactly uou are trying to changed the avatar if not in users section of wordpress?

Comment: Thank you very much for your availability, I try to explain.
I created the account settings page, then with ACF + ACF Frontend I put a form on this page. All fields work correctly, name, surname, email etc.

After doing that, the only thing I still hadn't added to the settings page was the avatar change option. So I started looking for a solution. The first thing I did was create an image field with ACF to replace the wordpress avatar (gravatar). Everything worked fine but then there were two problems.

Comment: 1) the avatar only works in the backend and not in the frontend.

2) even if Frontend had worked, the biggest problem concerns the elimination of images from the media library, that is, if a user decides to change or delete their avatar, the image is still saved in the media library, occupying space unnecessarily.

After all the effort I relied on another plugin, namely One User Avatar. And this is where I tried to integrate this plugin into the ACF fields, and this is how I posted the question here on the stack.

Comment: I chose this plugin (One User Avatar) because of all, it has the ability to delete the image from the media library if the user decides to change or delete the avatar.

With the ACF documentation I also tried to insert a function that deletes images from the media library if the user decides to change the image field, but it didn't work.

In any case, I am looking for a solution that allows me to use avatars on the wordpress site by integrating it in some way in ACF.

I'd like to be able to write my own code from scratch that maybe works with ACF, but I don't have the skills.

Comment: Well your case seems quite complicated, changing the avatar of users and integrating ACF with default WordPress users avatar is very different. Well, I never used ACF before, so even if you want to change every user's avatar manually you can do it with the above example I provided. I assume what you are looking for is a big customization.

Comment: The idea of integrating any plugin with ACF comes from the fact that I don't want to find two Update Profile buttons in the settings page (one for the ACF fields and the other for the avatar).

This is why I had thought of integrating everything into the ACF fields. Apparently, however, it is too complicated and expensive.

As an alternative solution I also managed to create a form with all the ACF fields but the problem of the images remains in the Media library even after having been deleted from the profile.

Comment: Either way yes, it sounds complicated. I will try to get in touch with a programmer and get assistance for this custom work. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: However I would like to try the last thing. I know you said you have never used ACF and I am grateful to you for all the valuable answers you have given me.

Kindly, if you can and if you have more time to devote to me, take a look at this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70284474/acf-remove-image-from-wp-media-library-with-php-code

Being able to do what I wrote would solve the problem. Thanks anyway.